# Unsupported operand +

Tags: python, list, loops, tuples, range

I am trying to code a program that would add values of a combination but I'm getting this error message :

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'tuple
```

Here is my code :

```
from itertools import combinations

# values are 32, 20, 5, 18
objects = [
    ("golden purse", 32, 2),
    ("gold", 20, 5),
    ("iron statue", 5, 1),
    ("iron sword", 18, 6),
]


def combinaisons(l):
    tmp = []
    for i in range(1, len(l) + 1):
        tmp += list(combinations(l, i))
    return tmp


comb = combinaisons(objects)


def calc_values(l):
    somme = 0
    for c in range(len(l)):
        for i in range(len(l[c])):
            somme = somme + l[i][1]
        print(somme)


calc_values(comb)
```

**"l[i][1]" should be an integer such as 32 so I don't see where is the problem**

Comment: *"Should be"*… Have you checked that it *is*? E.g. simply by `print`ing it right before?

Comment: well it says that the `tuple index out of range` but I don't know how l[0][1] is out of range..

Comment: Well, you could figure it out if you did `print(l)`…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside `calc_values()`, `l` is

```
[ ( ('golden purse', 32, 2), ) , ...
^ ^ ^                       ^
| | tuple = l[0][0]         nothing = l[0][1]
| tuple = l[0]
array = l
```

`l[0]` is a tuple consisting of another tuple and nothing. `l[0][0]` would be the innermost tuple, `l[0][1]` is nothing. That's what you're trying to access.

An IDE like Pycharm provides you the ability to debug. It will stop at exceptions and give you the ability to inspect variables on the fly. Use it to your advantage.

[image: Values in the debugger]

Depending on what you want to sum to, you need

```
somme = somme + l[i][0][1]
```

or

```
somme = somme + l[i][0][2]
```

But actually I wonder whether the combinations are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
somme = somme + l[i][0][1]
```

instead of

```
somme = somme + l[i][1]
```